# Python Import issue With PyQt4.QtCore

Tags: pyqt4, qtcore

`from PyQt4.QtCore import *` works in PyCharm but doesn't work with Python3 and PyQt4 on the Raspberry Pi.  I checked under usr/... and QtCore is shown.  I figure Raspbian doesn't like the .Qtcore so I've tried to change it to another format `from PyQt4 import QtCore` Pycharm gives errors that Qt is not defined.  The only thing in Pycharm that works is 'from PyQt4.QtCore import *' and I've tried everything I can find. Can anyone tell me why the second part won't work in PyCharm and what the correct format is so it will work under Raspbian?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the full tracebacks from the errors you are getting.

Comment: Of course Qt isn't defined in PyCharm when you use `from PyQt4 import QtCore`, you need to reference it as `QtCore.Qt`

Comment: Thank you Tim that was the problem.